# Adding to a dataset using another full dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, datatable, dataset

I am looking for a way to add one dataset to another in a foreach loop in C#.

```
public DataTable getFiles(List<string> userIDs)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dtFileContents = new DataTable();
    string spUpdate = "usp_Update";
    string spSelect = "usp_Select";

    try
    {
        foreach (string item in userIDs)
        {
            ds = OracleConnectionHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, spSelect.ToUpper(), userIDs);
            OracleConnectionHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, spUpdate.ToUpper(), userIDs);
        }

        dtFileContents = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return dtFileContents;
}
```

So, all I need is a way not to overwrite the previous dataset. Something like ds += ... but I cannot find it anywhere.

I thought about merging datasets, but I don't know how many datasets I will need.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve. What means _"overwrite the previous dataset. Something like ds += ..."_ ? Have you tried [`DataTable.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DataSet.Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are quite right. I was trying to first select records in my database before they are updated, and then update my database based on userIds. Each user ID is going to pull back attributes of any number of files. So, I want these attributes in a Datatable. The next time the loop excutes a new datable will be returned with the same columns. I want to append that datatable to the end of the old datatable for a gridview. The merge worked perfectly. I must have been doing something wrong when I tried previously. Thank you  for your help. If you post this, I will mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't absolutely imperitive that you return a single result set, you could change your method's signature to return a list of them:

```
public IEnumerable<DataTable> getFiles(List<string> userIDs)
{
    var result = new List<DataTable>();
    string spUpdate = "usp_Update";
    string spSelect = "usp_Select";

    try
    {
        foreach (string item in userIDs)
        {

            DataSet ds = OracleConnectionHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, spSelect.ToUpper(), userIDs);
            OracleConnectionHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, spUpdate.ToUpper(), userIDs);

            result.Add(ds.Tables[0]);
        }


        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, you may simply have to write another method that manually appends the contents of one DataTable to another. As you've indicated, a merge is likely not what you want, since it will treat inserts and updates differently, and I suspect that what you want is the equivalent of a SQL UNION.

```
public void Join (DataTable existing, DataTable newContent)
{
    foreach (var row in newContent.Rows)
    {
       var newRow = existing.NewRow();
       // Copy data over
       existing.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.